# Asserting an exception in QUnit

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, qunit, assertion, throws

I am working on a unit test that is testing a generated parser code from a grammar. ( generated via PegJS)
Im almost finished with most of the cases that are possible. There are 2-3 of them left and they are expected to throw an exception but i can't seem to figure out how to assert an exception.

```
(function () {

    "use strict";

    QUnit.module('durationTests');

    QUnit.test('durationParseTest', function (assert) {

        var dp1 = DurationParser.parse(new String('')); //this is the one that is expected to throw exception 
        var dp2 = DurationParser.parse(new String('P'));
        var dp3 = DurationParser.parse(new String('P13MT2H'));
        var dp4 = DurationParser.parse(new String('P2Y6M'));

        assert.deepEqual(dp2,[]);
        assert.deepEqual(dp3, [
            {
                "type": "M",
                "val": 13
            },
            {
                "type": "T"
            },
            {
                "type": "H",
                "val": 2
            }
        ]);
```

there are many other cases but I included only these two to show how I tested them. They are working just fine right now.

The thing I don't get about QUnit throw assertion is that I don't know how to give the assertion this *spesific* parse function. Any help is appreciated.

**Edit:** I tried many of the suggested ways in QUnit website but still can't figure out how to test that spesific exception properly.

Comment: Glad you got this on your own! You should add an answer below to your own question, and then accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to test the exception succesfully , im sharing the answer if anybody is interested

```
QUnit.test("Invalid string input throws SyntaxError", function (assert) {
        assert.throws(
            function () {
                DurationParser.parse(new String(''));
            },
            function (error) {
                return error.name === "SyntaxError";
            }
        );
    });
```

QUnit website was not helpful at all, I figured it out by just trying different variations of this syntax.